# Running Montavista Linux kernel 2.6.21 on XEN

Tags: linux, xen

I've been assigned the task of getting our MontaVista Linux (2.6.21 kernel) running on Xen.

We'll be running Xen in -hvm- mode.

My Xen version is 3.4.0 (linux kernel 2.6.18) and am unable to run MontaVista Linux (kernel 2.6.21) in hvm mode.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Has your Xen installation been able to running any dom0 of any sort ?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have any problems running any Linux distro in HVM mode on Xen, as HVM presents a true "Virtual Machine" interface to the guest OS.  You're going to have to expand greatly on the details behind "unable" to get any useful assistance, because it really should work.

Comment: #xm info
release                : 2.6.18.8-xen
machine                : i686
nr_cpus                : 8
cpu_mhz                : 2400
virt_caps              : hvm hvm_directio

domain_config file.
kernel = "bzImage"
cpus = "1"
memory = 2048
pci = [ '05:00.0', '05:00.1' ]
name = "foo"

bzImage is a bootable MontaVista image with 2.6.21 kernel.
[root@localhost]# xm create -p domain_config1
Using config file "./domain_config1".
Error: (2, 'Invalid kernel', 'xc_dom_find_loader: no loader found\n')
[root@localhost ios]# 

Josh.

Comment: There are so many things wrong here I don't know where to start... first off, don't put info like that in a comment, edit your question.  Second, that's not how you create, nor how you start, an HVM domain.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've modified my domain_config as follows.
kernel = "/usr/lib/xen/boot/hvmloader"
builder='hvm'
arch_libdir = 'lib'

cpus = "1"

## Initial memory allocation (in megabytes) for the new domain.

memory = 1024

pci = [ '05:00.0', '05:00.1' ]

## A name for your domain. All domains must have different names.

name = "foo"

device_model = '/usr/' + arch_libdir + '/xen/bin/qemu-dm'

serial='pty'

disk = [ 'file:xenguest.img,hda,w', 'file:bzImage,hdb,r' ]

I can see the VM starting and then crashing.

/var/log/xend-debug.log shows the following.

Xend started at Sun Aug  2 00:59:40 2009.
Unhandled exception in thread started by
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//usr/lib/python/xen/xend/image.py", line 549, in _sentinel_watch
    self._dmfailed(message)
  File "//usr/lib/python/xen/xend/image.py", line 491, in _dmfailed
    xc.domain_shutdown(self.vm.getDomid(), DOMAIN_CRASH)
TypeError: an integer is required
Unhandled exception in thread started by
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//usr/lib/python/xen/xend/image.py", line 549, in _sentinel_watch
    self._dmfailed(message)
  File "//usr/lib/python/xen/xend/image.py", line 491, in _dmfailed
    xc.domain_shutdown(self.vm.getDomid(), DOMAIN_CRASH)
TypeError: an integer is required
Unhandled exception in thread started by
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//usr/lib/python/xen/xend/image.py", line 549, in _sentinel_watch
    self._dmfailed(message)
  File "//usr/lib/python/xen/xend/image.py", line 491, in _dmfailed
    xc.domain_shutdown(self.vm.getDomid(), DOMAIN_CRASH)
xen.lowlevel.xc.Error: (3, 'No such process')
Unhandled exception in thread started by
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//usr/lib/python/xen/xend/image.py", line 549, in _sentinel_watch
    self._dmfailed(message)
  File "//usr/lib/python/xen/xend/image.py", line 491, in _dmfailed
    xc.domain_shutdown(self.vm.getDomid(), DOMAIN_CRASH)
TypeError: an integer is required
~